# Ubuntu noob, problem with IP masquerading; "Error saving the document ufw"?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm a noob and I'm used to the limited version of Ubuntu offered on TAILS, never did anything really technical with it, so i'm a complete noob here. I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I have an UFW enabled, allowed ssh/tcp, logging is on, all that stuff, just following the basic UFW guide on ubuntu wiki.

Anyways, I found the slightly less basic guide for Firewall on ubuntu wiki (https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/firewall.html) and I attempted to set up IP masquerading for my firewall. So, I tried to open LibreOffice and attempted to edit the document /etc/default/ufw and tried editing the text so that the default forward policy would be set to ACCEPT, so that packets could be forwarded.

Every time I try to save the document after editing it, it first asks if i want to save it in .odt or .txt. No matter which option I choose, i always get the following error message

Error saving the document ufw: /etc/default/ufw.txt does not exist.

Or .odt depending on which format i tried saving it in. So, what gives here? Shouldn't that file exist? Is it a problem if it says it doesnt exist when I attempt to save it. Do i need to do something else first? I'm just full of questions and Ive no idea here, so nay help would be appreciated :) I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, I just figured asking an honest community for help when I need it would be the best choice. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The document is just called `/etc/default/ufw`, there is no `.txt` or `.odt`extension on the file name.

In fact, if you save it with one of these extensions, it will not work as desired since the `ufw` program looks for a file called simply `ufw`.

To see if it already exists, you can list it by typing `cat /etc/default/ufw` in a terminal window (it is not a very big file)

Try editing it with `gedit` which is a simple text editor.

The file is also owned by `root`, so you will not be able to save your changes unless you do so as `root`, by typing `gksudo gedit /etc/default/ufw` in a terminal.

A window will pop up and ask you to enter your password, then you will be able to edit the file and save your changes.